# Что означают эти символы в языке Ассемблера

Tags: ассемблер

Вот часть кода

```
;Здесь определяются данные
string db 'This is the result line of the program',13,10,'$'
ends
```

мне непонятны цифры 13, 10 и символ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

13 - Carriage return, возврат курсора в первую позицию строки

10 - Line feed, перевод курсора на новую строку.

Это непечатные символы таблицы [ASCII](https://www.ascii-code.com/) используются для управления курсором (раньше для управления печатной головкой принтера).

После печати такого вывода, следующий вывод будет начинаться с первой позиции следующей строки.

$ в конце фиксирует длину строки.

```
len  equ  $ - db
```

должен записать в len длину строки.

Comment: Про `$` это не так. В данном случае это обычный символ. А строка явно подготовлена для передачи функции 9 прерывания 21h (dos), которая выводит на экран строку и она использует знак `$` как признак конца строки

Comment: Я руководствовался этим - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_strings.htm

там как раз $ используется для вычисления длины строки (как один из вариантов).

Comment: Да, я это понял, но там $ используется как элемент языка, он не в кавычках. А вопросе он в кавычках, так что он просто символ. И да, когда он элемент языка он обозначает "текущий адрес", поэтому будучи расположенным за строкой позволяет вычислить ее размер в момент компиляции

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо за уточнение. Ассемблер как-то мимо меня прошел.

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ